# Static like methods in Android application with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to add a "static" method to my MyApplication class in kotlin
I have added (as a property) the variable :

```
private var context: Context? = null
```

in method:

```
override fun onCreate()
```

I added:

```
context = applicationContext
```

then I add a companion object like this

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic fun getMyApplicationContext(): Context?
    {
        return MyApplication().context
    }
}
```

when I call this method from other parts of the application like
`MyApplication.getMyApplicationContext()` it always returns null. I have gleaned all this from several sources but I am not sure if it is anywhere near correct or not.

Comment: With `return MyApplication().context` you are creating a new MyApplication Object. Then you are accessing the context with `.context`, which is null because `onCreate()` does not get called when you manually create your object.

Comment: context looks like an instance variable, you're trying to access an instance variable from a static function which you cannot do.

Move the declaration of context into the companion object to make it static as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a global application context object. Now casting aside my dislike for global variables, I think you are pretty close.

I think you just need to add the variable into the `MyApplication` classes companion object and use that directly. You only need the `@JvmField` annotation if you're going to access the field from Java.

```
class MyApplication {
   companion object {
      @JvmField
      var context: Context? = null

      // Not really needed since we can access the variable directly.
      @JvmStatic fun getMyApplicationContext(): Context? {
        return context
      }
   }

   override fun onCreate() {
     ...
     MyApplication.context = appContext
   }
}
```

Comment: In Android you don't create `Context` instances yourself, they are created for you.

Comment: @nhaarman In that case you just need to set the `MyApplication.context` when you're given the `Context`. Presumably this is in the MyApplication constructor?

Comment: Actually looking at the code fragments in the original question it looks like the initialization of the companion object was happening in `onCreate`, so I'll just change it to do that too.